# Merging a split string in python

Tags: python, pandas, split

I'm reading a csv file in Python and trying to split the values in one of the columns such that I can parse off a certain values.

My input would look something like this:

```
ColA
AA_BBB_CCC_DDD
AAA_BBBB_CCC_DDDDDD
AAAA_B_ZZ_CC_DDD
AAA_BBB_CCCC_DDDD
```

The entries would get split on an underscore(_). Using the following

```
jobs = pd.read_csv(somefile.csv)

jobs["Val1"] = jobs["ColA"].str.split("_",  expand=True)[1]
jobs["Val2"] = jobs["ColA"].str.split("_",  expand=True)[2]

print(jobs["Val1"])
print(jobs["Val2"])
```

That works and give me output like this -

```
0     WRE
1     BBB
2    BBBB
3       B
4     BBB
Name: Val1, dtype: object
0     CMD
1     CCC
2     CCC
3      ZZ
4    CCCC
Name: Val2, dtype: object
```

My issue is there are instances where the underscore is actually part of Val1 and shouldn't be dropped. If Val1 is 2 characters or less, than Val1 really needs to be combined with Val2 to get the correct value.

For example the third entry in my example. Val1 would be "B" while Val2 would be "ZZ". As Val1 is only one character, then the true value of Val1 should be "B_ZZ".

To try and achieve that I'm doing the following –

```
if len(jobs["Val1"]) <=2:
    jobs["Val1"] = jobs["Val1"] + "_" + jobs["Val2"]
```

However that doesn't do anything for me. I get the same result as not including it at all.

If I change the <= value to 5, which is certainly incorrect, it then does the merge. However it does it on all values, with output looking like this -

```
0     WRE_CMD
1     BBB_CCC
2    BBBB_CCC
3        B_ZZ
4    BBB_CCCC
Name: Val1, dtype: object
0     CMD
1     CCC
2     CCC
3      ZZ
4    CCCC
Name: Val2, dtype: object
```

I'm not sure what I'm missing with here. Or if there is a better approach to what I'm trying to achieve.

Sorry for the long winded note.

Thanks

Comment: `len(jobs["Val1"])` is the length of the *column*, not the length of the string in each cell.

Comment: In short, `if len(jobs["Val1"]) <=2: jobs["Val1"] = jobs["Val1"] + "_" + jobs["Val2"]` is not doing what you think it's doing.  It's combining the *entire* two series by `"_"` if there are more than 2 rows in `jobs["Val1"]`.  It would probably help if you can provide an example of what is your expected outcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where you are trying this:

```
if len(jobs["Val1"]) <=2:
    jobs["Val1"] = jobs["Val1"] + "_" + jobs["Val2"]
```

Instead, you can pass a function that does this via `apply`

```
def adjust_val1(row):
    if len(row['val1']) <= 2:
        return row['val1'] + '_' + row['val2']
    else:
        return row['val1']
```

and then

```
jobs['val3'] = jobs.apply(adjust_val1, axis=1)
```

Comment: Its giving me a Traceback error that I don't understand where the issue lies - `KeyError: ('Val1', 'occurred at index ColA') `

Comment: try changing the axis argument in apply to 0 or 1. apply, by deafault applies by column. we need it to apply by row

Answer (score 1):

You can use `df['ColA'].str.split` with a negative lookbehind regex:

```
df['ColA'].str.split(r'(?<!_[A-Za-z])_', expand=True)
      0     1     2       3
0    AA   BBB   CCC     DDD
1   AAA  BBBB   CCC  DDDDDD
2  AAAA  B_ZZ    CC     DDD
3   AAA   BBB  CCCC    DDDD
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `numpy` maybe this can help

```
jobs["Val3"] = np.where(jobs.Val1.str.len()<=2, jobs.Val1+"_"+jobs.Val2, jobs.Val1)

                  ColA  Val1  Val2  Val3
0       AA_BBB_CCC_DDD   BBB   CCC   BBB
1  AAA_BBBB_CCC_DDDDDD  BBBB   CCC  BBBB
2     AAAA_B_ZZ_CC_DDD     B    ZZ  B_ZZ
3    AAA_BBB_CCCC_DDDD   BBB  CCCC   BBB
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try to use a function using apply method:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['col'] = pd.Series(['AA_BBB_CCC_DDD','AAA_BBBB_CCC_DDDDDD','AAAA_B_ZZ_CC_DDD','AAA_BBB_CCCC_DDDD'])

df:
    col
0   AA_BBB_CCC_DDD
1   AAA_BBBB_CCC_DDDDDD
2   AAAA_B_ZZ_CC_DDD
3   AAA_BBB_CCCC_DDDD
```

A function to split as you wish:

```
def get_val1(x):
    l = x.split('_')
    if len(l[1]) < 2:
        return l[1] + '_' + l[2]
    else:
        return l[1]

df['val1'] = df['col'].apply(lambda x: get_val1(x))
```

Resultado val1:

```
0     BBB
1    BBBB
2    B_ZZ
3     BBB
Name: val1, dtype: object

df["val2"] = df["col"].str.split("_",  expand=True)[2]
```

Result:

```
    col                 val1    val2
0   AA_BBB_CCC_DDD      BBB     CCC
1   AAA_BBBB_CCC_DDDDDD BBBB    CCC
2   AAAA_B_ZZ_CC_DDD    B_ZZ    ZZ
3   AAA_BBB_CCCC_DDDD   BBB     CCCC
```